# Multiplying some rows by other rows in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

How should I accomplish the following "multiplication"?  I'd like to multiply "X" by "Y" and store it as "Z".

I use a combination of three columns to determine the two rows to multiply, and a select column to determine which two to multiply.  Lastly, I multiply two values.  It looks like this::

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1':['A','A','A','A'],
               'key2':['B','B','B','B'],
               'key3':['C','C','D','D'],
               'val1':[10,11,30,-3],
               'val2':[20,25,40,-2],
               'sel':['X','Y','X','Y']})

     key1 key2 key3 sel  val1  val2 
0    A    B    C    X    10    20
1    A    B    C    Y    11    25
2    A    B    D    X    30    40
3    A    B    D    Y    -3    -2
```

In order to decide which records to multiply I use the three keys.  in this case, record 0 has keys A, B and C and sel=X.  I want to do an element-wise multiply that by the other record that has keys A, B and C and sel=Y.
So, the result will be 10x11 for val1, and 20*25 for val2.  There is another record that should be created as well (ABDX times ABDY) where val1 = 30*-3 and val2 = 40*-2

```
    key1 key2 key3 sel val1 val2
0   A    B    C    Z    110 500
1   A    B    D    Z    -90 -80
```

Right now the only thing on my mind is to iteratively break the rows down into unique combinations of the keys, and do the multiply for each combination. I'm hoping for an idea or a direction that I can try so I don't have to iterate through a data frame.  There are hundreds of unique combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply `groupby` your keys and then `prod`:

```
In [34]: p = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], as_index=False).prod()

In [35]: p
Out[35]: 
  key1 key2 key3  val1  val2
0    A    B    C   110   500
1    A    B    D   -90   -80
```

You can then add sel=Z in several different ways, whether direct assignment or using `.insert` (which is shorter but a little less general).  For example:

```
In [38]: p = df.groupby(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], as_index=False).prod()

In [39]: p.assign(sel='Z').reindex(columns=df.columns)
Out[39]: 
  key1 key2 key3 sel  val1  val2
0    A    B    C   Z   110   500
1    A    B    D   Z   -90   -80
```

Answer (score 1):

set `key1`, `key2`, `key3` to index and then do the calculation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1':['A','A','A','A'],
               'key2':['B','B','B','B'],
               'key3':['C','C','D','D'],
               'val1':[10,11,30,-3],
               'val2':[20,25,40,-2],
               'sel':['X','Y','X','Y']})

df2 = df.set_index(["key1", "key2", "key3"])[["val1", "val2"]]

g = df2.groupby(df.sel.values)
(g.get_group("X") * g.get_group("Y")).reset_index().assign(sel="Z")
```